# Client to call a webservice written using axis 1.4

Tags: soap, jax-ws, axis

I have webservice written in axis 1.4. Currently I am able to consume the services using the same Axis 1.4 client. I am trying to create client to consume the SOAP based web service *other than axis1.4* I did try doing that using below, but getting following exception:

```
    QName reportReq = new 
             QName("http://xmlns.com/Message","MessageService");    
    URL url = new URL(webserviceUrl);
    Service service = Service.create(url, reportReq);
    Call call = (Call)service.getPort(ReportRequest.class);
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(webserviceUrl);
    **strong text**call.setOperationName(reportReq);
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Error 
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class:
           at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1445)
           at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:367)
           at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:387)
```

Can anyone suggest how can I get rid of this issue?